# error to change user ad from OU to powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell

I'm creating a script to change certain OU users, but it gives a parameter error and it's not working.

Users and OUs are being listed through an .csv file, the strings get the information, but when putting it in the code line it doesn't work.

```
Import-Csv -Path  C:\Users\leonan.martins\Desktop\teste1.csv -Delimiter ',' -PipelineVariable User | ForEach-Object -Process {
   
        $us = $User.user
    $OU1 = $User.Regiao
        $OU2 = $User.Diretoria
        $OU3 = $User.Area
    get-aduser $User | move-adobject -TargetPath "OU=$OU1,OU=$OU2,OU=$OU3,DC=lab,DC=suporti,DC=local"
}
```

Comment: By `.xml file` I assume you meant `.csv file` ? Also, please share the specific error message you're getting.

Comment: there was a mistake, is .csv file

Comment: I believe the issue was with the typo on `get-aduser $User` instead of `get-aduser $Us`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likable cause of your error is a typo on `$us = $User.user` and the referencing `$User` in the `Get-ADUser` call instead of `$us`. As for `-PipelineVariable User`, you could replace it for [`$_` (also known as `$PSItem`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#_) to refer to the *current object being passed through the pipeline*:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\leonan.martins\Desktop\teste1.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $target = [string]::Format(
        "OU={0},OU={1},OU={2},DC=lab,DC=suporti,DC=local",
        $_.Regiao, $_.Diretoria, $_.Area
    )
    Get-ADUser $_.User | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $target
}
```

Comment: Hi Santiago, could you send me your email? I would like to chat with you about powershell.

Comment: @LeonanMoreiraMartins hi, you can find my contact details in my profile details. If you want to chat add me in LinkedIn

Answer (score 0):

Add the DN of your target OU in your script, and you can do it as simple as this:

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "D:\Powershell\Input\UsersList.csv" #Path to CSV-File
$TargetOU = "OU=Target,OU=kj,DC=kj,DC=local" #DistinguishedName of Target OU 

foreach($User in $Users)
{
    Get-ADUser $User.SamAccountName | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $TargetOU
}
```